# TypeError: .some Is not A Function React JS Error

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, error-handling

`const [userFavorites, setUserFavorites]= useState([]);` This is the part of my code that sets the state of userFavorites to an array and I have a function somewhere else that tries to do `userFavorites.some` and I keep `TypeError: userFavorites.some is not a function`. I appreciate any help!

Comment: if you console.log userFavorites what does it return. It seems that it might not be an array

Comment: Please show more of your code. ANything that can change userFavorites especially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can post the entire code snippet then it will be helpful to answer. Though you're possibly doing something like this.

Initially, it is declared as an empty array `[]`, But there is a possibility that somewhere in your code you're setting the state like this.

```
  setUserFavorites(someDataFromAPICallORPostOperation).
```

Here, Your `someDataFromAPICallORPostOperation` is possibly undefined.

You can solve this in two ways.

**1. Default to an empty array while setting the state.**

```
  setUserFavorites(someDataFromAPICallORPostOperation ?? []).
```

**2. Check for the `undefined` before calling the `.some` function.**

```
userFavorites?.some(function) // Using optional chaining
```

or

```
userFavorites && userFavorites.some(function)
```

**EDIT** - Based on the code mentioned in the commented link.

The array [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) operation doesn't return the updated array, Instead, it returns the number of elements in the updated array.

This can be solved as

```
    function addFavoritesHandler(favoriteMeetup) {
        setUserFavorites(prevUserFavorites => {
            return [...prevUserFavorites, favoriteMeetup];
        });
    }
```

Explanation, Earlier you were doing something like this.

```
    function addFavoritesHandler(favoriteMeetup) {
        setUserFavorites(prevUserFavorites => {
            return prevUserFavorites.push(favoriteMeetup);
        });
    }
```

Here you will set the state to a number instead of an array as `push` will return the number of elements in that array. Hence, while doing `userFavorites.some` it throws an error as you are setting the `userFavorites` to a number instead of an array.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/rLHT3i9V That is the code for the js file creating the userFavorites and the js file using the other js file.

Comment: @Airlo I have updated the answer. See the `Edit` part at the end of this answer.